# Should I remove feature or make it ineffective?

Tags: programming-practices, software

I have code for a game that I want to change, make different game but with same mechanics and design.

There are some features that I don't want to have in game.

I have 2 options:

#### 1) Remove feature

Deleting code will definitely remove feature but may take time and cause some bugs.

Pros:

- Less complex code
- Better for maintenance

Cons:

- Harder to do
- May cause bugs

#### 2) Make it ineffective

For example, if I want player not to receive damage, I can set damage multiplier to 0

Pros:

- Easy
- Features can be reused later

Cons:

- Higher complexity
- Harder maintenance
- Slowing down application (by a tiny bit)

Am I missing something ? What is the best practice ?

Comment: In your code-base, is it possible to leave the class/function that does alone and just comment out where it's called? This way you'd avoid deleting the feature, it would just never get used.

Comment: @KingGraham In some cases yes, but some features are all over many classes.

Comment: In your case it might be easier to set the damage to 0 in the short-term. In the long-term you might want to de-couple your code so that disabling some features is easier.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should bet on a progressive feature removal.

1. Collect all the functions that represent the feature you want to remove and label them as *Deprecated*.
2. Make sure that those functions don't perform any change in the system (*set damage multiplier to 0*)
3. Evolve your system and remove the deprecated code progressively.